# concatenate date and time fields into DateTime field

Tags: apex

I have a custom date field and a picklist field for time (holding values eg. 00:00 
00:15 etc). I want to concatenate them into a single dateTime variable. currently I am using this :

```
dateTime newDateTime = DATETIMEVALUE(string.valueOf((ac.Start_Date__c.year())) +'-'+ string.valueOf(ac.Start_Date__c.month())+'-'+ string.valueOf(ac.Start_Date__c.day())+' ' + string.valueOf(ac.Start_Time__c) +':00');
```

But its not working. It is saying :

```
Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: DATETIMEVALUE(String)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use "formulas" in Apex Code. Instead, use the DateTime constructors. You might do something like this:

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(
    ac.Start_Date__c, 
    Time.newInstance(
        Integer.valueOf(ac.Start_Time__c.split(':')[0]),
        Integer.valueof(ac.Start_Time__c.split(':')[1]), 
    0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

strDate = string.valueOf(Start_Date__c);

strTime = string.valueOf(Start_Time__c);

strDateTime = strDate + ' ' + strTime;

newDateTime = DateTime.valueOf(strDateTime);